# Font viewer that supports viewing ligatures

Tags: fonts

How can I debug a font's ligature glyphs?

For example, I have configured Iosevka with the following ligature:

```
[[iosevka.compLig]]
unicode = 57673 # 0xe149
featureTag = 'XHS0'
sequence = "->"
```

How can I view the glyph to confirm that `->` is being displayed as an arrow? Certain applications have their own logic, so I would rather see it in a font viewer in a more application-independent form if possible. For example, I would like to be able to confirm if a ligature does *not* exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open [Font Manager](https://fontmanager.github.io/).
2. Select your font.
3. Click **Preview**.
4. Click **Ab** to make the preview font editable.
5. Enter your potentially ligated string into the preview box.
6. Visually confirm or deny the presence of a ligature.